# Can anyone help me write some code? It's pretty easy but I'm too dumb to understand

Tags: python

The question is:

> Enter a minimum and maximum number followed by a unknown number.
> If this number is not within the maximum and minimum values, the programming will be stopped.
>
> When it is less than 50, print it out except for even numbers.
> When it is higher than 50 and lower than 80, except for multiples of 3 and even numbers, the rest are printed.
> Numbers greater than 80 are discarded.
>
> tips:
>
> ```
>   a != 2 ("a" isn't 2)
> ```

using `if`, `else`, `elif`, `for`, `break`, and `continue`.

Comment: Asking basically "Can someone help me?" isn't an actual question"  and is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1):

The question is very unclear but i guess it wants something like this:

```
min_, max_, num = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
if not min_ <= num <= max_:
    exit()

if num < 50 and not (num % 2 == 0):
    print(num)

if 50 <= num < 80 and not (num % 3 == 0) and not (num % 2 == 0):
    print(num)
```